# TDD without local database?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, database, unit-testing, tdd

When we develop a Rails application then we use a local database in our development environment, and make sure that our specs pass as part of TDD.

Is it a norm to not use a local database similar to Sqlite while doing TDD in Java? I have been told in-memory database(HSQL) is all that is needed for running unit and integration tests. Is this a standard practice being followed?

We use Sqlite in our Rails application for local development and for running our Rspecs. But my question is for Java development. We are working on rewritting a part of our application in Java. I have been told that you do not need any database for development if you write integration tests covering all functionality. And have been told that HSQL is sufficient for that. As I am used to having database for local development in Rails, I am wondering how you debug any issues later on? It is quite helpful to analyze any issues if we can replicate the data and scenario in local environment. How do you do same in Java/Spring if you do not use any database for development environment and rely completely on HSQL for testing?

Comment: don't use the db  at all in unit testing

Comment: You can use HSQLDB in file: mode instead of mem: mode. You will get a human readable .script file with all the DDL and test data as SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I never use any databases including *HSQLDB* to write an unit-test.

I prefer to create some `interface`s like as: `*Repository`. and let's the SUT communicate with it. and then I write some implementation class let them implement the interface which I have created. and the classes hierarchy looks like below:

```
          <<uses>>
  SUT  ---------------> Repository
                            ^
                            | <<implement>>
                            |
               |--------|--------|-------|
               |        |        |       |
              JPA    Hibernate  JDBC    .etc
```

this approach is known as [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). the application domain is a concern, data accessing is another concern. following this approach result in many **plug-compatible** components and **independent** modules, such as: `domain`, `jpa`, `jdbc`, and .etc, but the **important** thing is that will make your test is more **testable**.

**Then** I use [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html)s to mock/stub out its collaboration in unit-test to testing them are work together as expected. the pseudo-code like as below:

```
repo = mock(Repository.class);
SUT it = new SUT(repository);

when(repo.find(id)).thenReturn(entity);

assert it.exercise() == expectedResult;
assert it.currentState == expectedState;
```

**But** you must write some integration test using **database** to testing each `Repository` implementation that operate on the third-party api. it is called by Martin: [Test Isolation](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TestIsolation).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question: is very common to have your test environment database as close as the development environment as possible.

I suppose that you are preoccupied with performance, there are more crucial things that you could improve before considering having an in-memory database.

Usually while TDD-ing you would only run the tests involved and later run your whole suite to check that you didn't break anything. If you are using Rspec you could use [tags](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/command-line/tag-option).

Another important thing is to clean the database at the beginning of every test since tests should be isolated and never depend on the result of previous tests. This will improve complex search queries that you could have in your system. there is a [gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) that could help you here.

Finally, if you are using some sort of continuous integration tool remember to set it up using `rake db:schema:load` instead of `rake db:migrate`. This will run your schema file as a single migration instead of running each single migration every time you commit. (Remember to keep this version-controlled and always up to date)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting terminology wrong. TDD is about writing test cases in general. But most of the time, and also in your question, one thinks about using TDD for *unit testing*.

And unfortunately, terms are not very clear. When you turn to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), you find there (my words): "anything you do to test a piece of software" can be called a unit test.

But that isn't helpful. You should rather look for definitions such as [here](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/). And the main aspect there: unit tests work in isolation. Quoting from that link:

> Runs in memory (no DB or File access, for example)

Thus:

- when doing unit testing, you *should* not use **any** database
- when you integration tests, you want to ensure that your solution works "end to end". In that sense you might be using a special *instance* of your database, but not a different *kind* of database.